# Comparing Different Numeric Types In MSTest

Tags: c#

When AreEqual(T, T) is called with two different numeric types, I am getting equality reported back to me when I don't think I should. In the MSTest documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) for AreEqual(T, T), it says that 42L is not equal to 42. When I run the code below, as well as with a double and an integer, they are reported back as being equal to each other. I am assuming that some casting is being done somewhere, but what actually is happening under the hood? Why is it saying 42L and 42 are equal when the documentation says that they should not return equal for different numeric types?

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;


[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            long expected = 42L;
            int actual = 42;
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test_Divide()
        {
            int expected = 5;
            double actual = 5;
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
}
```

Comment: AreEqual() has a large number of overloads, but they are only designed for practical tests.  Where "practical" means that you don't have to test whether the language is somehow broken.  So you get AreEqual(object, object) and that's never true after the values are boxed.

Comment: Hover over each `AreEqual` call. Which overload of `AreEqual` is it calling? Why is that? How might https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table#remarks explain that?

Comment: _To be more explicit - the 42L comment is **not against the overload you are calling**._

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table) is what happends behind the scenes.

The most "wide" type is chosen to be T by the compiler and the smaller one is converted.